# Deploy endpoints to different region than the workspace in Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to deploy the endpoint for my model to a different location i.e **West Europe** as I have quota in that region for DS2_v2 compute machines. My default location for the workspace is **Germany West Central**.

Using Azure ML CLI for my building purposes and have the following configuration file.

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/managedOnlineEndpoint.schema.json
name: densenet121
auth_mode: key
location: westeurope
```

I'm running the following command also

```bash
az ml online-endpoint create --name $ENDPOINT_NAME -f create-endpoint.yaml --set location='westeurope'
```

Explicitly setting things too in the CLI command, still the endpoint gets created at germanywestcentral successfully. Is there anything that I can do to fix this thing out? I also need to create a deployment sequentially. I believe the solution would mirror in that situation too.

I've actually changed default configurations also in the CLI for the location. Upon running the given command:

```bash
az configure -l
```

The output is as following:

```bash
[
  {
    "name": "group",
    "source": "/Users/karnikkanojia/.azure/config",
    "value": "ComputerVisionHealthcare"
  },
  {
    "name": "workspace",
    "source": "/Users/karnikkanojia/.azure/config",
    "value": "ComputerVisionHealthcare"
  },
  {
    "name": "location",
    "source": "/Users/karnikkanojia/.azure/config",
    "value": "westeurope"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment will be created in the same location as the endpoint it is associated with.

If you want to create an online endpoint in a different location, you need to create an Azure Machine Learning workspace in that location first. Then, you can use the az ml online-endpoint create command and specify the resource group and workspace name of the new workspace.

Comment: Is there any way where I won’t have to create another workspace?